# Using case statement when joining two values SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please refer to the screenshot below

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZnHL.png)

The below query should definitely join the HELD_PARAM and the HELD_VALUE fields together as HEADER

```
SELECT *
    ,ISNULL(HDR_PARAM, '')  + ISNULL(HELD_VALUE, '') AS HEADER  
FROM "dbo"."T_table"
```

I was trying to hardcode one HELD_VALUE to reflect a different result like in the screenshot below. Could someone tell me what's wrong with the query?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbahN.png)

```
SELECT *,
     ISNULL(HDR_PARAM, '')  + (ISNULL(HELD_VALUE, ''), 
                CASE WHEN HELD_VALUE = 'Y' THEN 'Z'
                ELSE HELD_VALUE
    END) AS HEADER
FROM "dbo"."T_table"
```

Comment: LukStorms, All the parentheses are accounted for lol. If you notice near END, that's where I closed the parentheses. I believe this is more of a syntax error

Comment: How can I modify the query so that I would get the below results:

X=Z

ABCDEF

ASDDSA

Answer (score 2):

You could use CONCAT instead. It ignores NULL's

```
SELECT *,
 CONCAT(HDR_PARAM,
        CASE 
        WHEN HELD_VALUE = 'Y' THEN 'Z'
        ELSE HELD_VALUE
        END) AS HEADER
FROM "dbo"."T_table"
```

I know CONCAT isn't exactly standard SQL. But a lot of the databases have it. (although Oracle's version only accepts 2 params)

Answer (score 1):

You could put the `CASE` inside the `ISNULL` like follows:

```
SELECT *,
    ISNULL(HDR_PARAM, '')  +
    ISNULL
    (
        CASE WHEN HELD_VALUE = 'Y'
            THEN 'Z'
            ELSE HELD_VALUE END,
        ''
    ) AS HEADER
FROM "dbo"."T_table"
```

Answer (score 1):

To replicate your 2nd screenshot:

```
SELECT
*,
ISNULL(HDR_PARAM, '') AS HDR_PARAM,
ISNULL(HELD_VALUE, '') AS HELD_VALUE,
CASE
    WHEN HELD_VALUE = 'Y' THEN (HDR_PARAM + 'Z')
    ELSE (HDR_PARAM + HELD_VALUE)
    END AS HEADER
FROM "dbo"."T_table"
```

Note that string concat using `+` is not supported in all SQL engines; some require a `CONCAT` function or similar method.